# How do I get my MediaWiki site to use templates?

Tags: mediawiki, template

My MediaWiki site is currently using v1.24.4.

I don't seem to have many templates installed, and some very important ones seem to be missing.  For example, I can't use the Reference List template.  If I do put references in an article, with {{reflist}} at the bottom, the template comes across as a redlink:

```
Template:Reflist
```

Are templates something that have to be installed separately?  And if so, how do I go about it.

My site is hosted by DreamHost.

Comment: MediaWiki doesn't use templates, it uses [User Styles](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Gallery_of_user_styles), refer to documentation on installing as it would be too board on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Yes Templates have to be installed separately, see  [Mediawiki:Help:Templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates)